# How create keybindings for Evil command line?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

For example, I have created a keybinding for Emacs mini-buffer, that will receive the `[f9]`-key as a confirmation (usually the `RET`-key).

```
 (define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "<f9>") 'exit-minibuffer)
```

I use Evil mode, so would like to make a keybinding to `RET` in the Evil command buffer (after when you're pressing `:`). So that he will interpret the [f9]-key as an Enter/confirmation key.

When looking up in the documentation of Evil, I notice there are 6 state maps defined, but none of them applies on the command line, while in Vim you could map the keybindings on the command line.

Any solution on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty interesting.  Evil does actually provide `evil-ex-map`, but it's for entering ex commands that are immediately executed without terminating them with `RET`.  So I've looked a bit at the guts of `evil-ex` to find out why `minibuffer-local-map` isn't doing anything useful here:

```
(minibuffer-with-setup-hook
    #'evil-ex-setup
  (setq result
        (read-from-minibuffer
         ":"
         (or initial-input
             (and evil-ex-previous-command
                  (format "(default: %s) " evil-ex-previous-command)))
         evil-ex-completion-map
         nil
         'evil-ex-history
         evil-ex-previous-command
         t)))
```

That third argument to `read-from-minibuffer` is the keymap used *instead* of `minibuffer-local-map` for tasks like terminating input. In other words, customize `evil-ex-completion-map` and you should be good to go:

```
 (eval-after-load 'evil-vars
   '(define-key evil-ex-completion-map (kbd "<f9>") 'exit-minibuffer))
```

Comment: Awesome, I learn here every time how I could it figure out myself. Thanks for your well written answer!